# How to get name/ date style bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am very new to using Latex and am writing my final math paper using overleaf.  Right now my references are enumerated in the bibliography section.  How do I get them to be of the form:

> [Das12] Anirban DasGupta.  *Fundamentals of Probability: A First Course*. Springer, New York, 2012.

instead of `[1] ...`?  Again I am very new to using latex so am confused by the various packages.  I have `\usepackage{natbib}` installed.  Also, is there a command to cite these references once in place?

Comment: Does replacing your `\bibliographystyle{...}` with `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` help? You may want to have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Bibliography_styles.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about how you create the formatted bibliography: By hand, or with a software tool, say, BibTeX?